# How to Get Project Type Guid of selected project in the Solution Explorer by using VS Package

Tags: vspackage, vs-extensibility

I've created the simple VS Package for adding new item in the context menu of solution explorer. In that I need to check Selected Project's Project Type GUID. How can i get this.

For example, One Solution contains the three different type of projects, like WindowFormsApplication, MVC Projects,WebApplication. While select the MVC Projects, we need to get that ProjectType GUID.

I've tried the followings in my Package.cs,

```
IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection = (IVsMonitorSelection)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection));

monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPtr, out projectItemId, out mis, out selectionContainerPtr);

IVsHierarchy hierarchy = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyPtr, typeof(IVsHierarchy)) as IVsHierarchy;

if (hierarchy != null)
{
     object prjItemObject;
     hierarchy.GetProperty(projectItemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out    prjItemObject);
     string projectTypeGuid;
      Project prjItem = prjItemObject as Project;
      projectTypeGuid = prjItem.Kind;
}
```

In that I get GUID as "FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC" for all selected Projects.

Could anyone please help me this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found answer for this,

Reference: https://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007016.aspx

```
public string GetProjectTypeGuids(EnvDTE.Project proj)
        {
            string projectTypeGuids = "";
            object service = null;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution solution = null;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierarchy hierarchy = null;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject aggregatableProject = null;
            int result = 0;
            service = GetService(proj.DTE, typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution));
            solution = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution)service;

            result = solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(proj.UniqueName, out hierarchy);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                aggregatableProject = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject)hierarchy;
                result = aggregatableProject.GetAggregateProjectTypeGuids(out projectTypeGuids);
            }

            return projectTypeGuids;
        }

        public object GetService(object serviceProvider, System.Type type)
        {
            return GetService(serviceProvider, type.GUID);
        }

        public object GetService(object serviceProviderObject, System.Guid guid)
        {
            object service = null;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;
            IntPtr serviceIntPtr;
            int hr = 0;
            Guid SIDGuid;
            Guid IIDGuid;

            SIDGuid = guid;
            IIDGuid = SIDGuid;
            serviceProvider = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)serviceProviderObject;
            hr = serviceProvider.QueryService(ref SIDGuid, ref IIDGuid, out serviceIntPtr);

            if (hr != 0)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            else if (!serviceIntPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                service = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(serviceIntPtr);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Release(serviceIntPtr);
            }

            return service;
        }
    }
```

Its working fine for my requirement.