# Get Project information from IVsHierarchy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I already get hold of a IVsHierarchy object, the information I want is the project type (WinForm, WPF, ASP, etc.), language (C#, VB, F#, etc.) and debug configuration (debug, release, x86, amd64, etc.). What the reliable way to get this information?

I can get an EnvDTE.Project from the IVsHierarchy, and it contains properties like [CodeModel.Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel.language.aspx), [Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.kind.aspx), and [ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.configurationmanager.activeconfiguration.aspx), but I’m not sure those are the right properties to check against. For example, the possible language values are as [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodellanguageconstants.aspx)

vsCMLanguageCSharp Visual C# constant.

vsCMLanguageIDL Microsoft IDL constant.

vsCMLanguageMC Visual C++ constant.

vsCMLanguageVB Visual Basic constant.

vsCMLanguageVC Visual C++ constant.

This seems to be a very limited list, where are the languages like F#?

It’s even worse for project kind, the only possible values are prjKindCSharpProject, prjKindVBProject, prjKindVSAProject. Is it possible to get more detailed information like C# ASP, VB WPF etc.?

Comment: Just a note: "debug, release, x86, amd64" are build/solution/project configuration (the first two) & platforms (the last two), not "debug configurations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx and [How to Get Project Type Guid of selected project in the Solution Explorer by using VS Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169583/how-to-get-project-type-guid-of-selected-project-in-the-solution-explorer-by-usi) gave me a fairly good idea of how to get the project type, and I can also figure out the language type from it. CodeModel seems to be the wrong approach to get it.